# Js file not being loaded on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Im doing a project from scratch and getting an anoying error that Im dealing without sucess.

Im trying to add a JS file to a page not having sucess.

Those are my files:

```
#application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require welcome
//= require_tree .
```

My welcome.js inside /assets/javascripts:

```
#/assets/javascripts/welcome.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#present').mouseenter(function(){
        alert("MouseEnter!"); // This will create an alert box
        console.log("MouseEnter!"); // This will log to the JS console on your browser which is a bit nicer to read than alerts, you do not need both, just preference
        $(this).fadeIn('fast',1);
    });

    $('#present').mouseleave(function(){
        alert("MouseLeave!"); // This will create an alert box
        console.log("MouseLeave!");
        $(this).fadeIn('fast',0.5);
    });
});
```

When I run the root page the JS is being shown looking at the inspector. But looks empty (i dont know if this is something usual)

```
src="/assets/welcome.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"
```

If I open it using the browser it shows:

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

Well. Someone know what can I do to make my Javascript works?

Thanks

Comment: try putting `require tree` at the end and restarting the server.

Comment: Doesnt work. The weird thing is that, even if i only put a "console.log" inside the $(document).ready nothing is shown

Comment: you're not closing the functions. `$('#present').mouseenter(function(){ //write it in between this });` you have not added `);` at the end of the function,

Comment: I did that. but too doesnt work Gagan. What is driving me crazy is that the $(document).ready its not being called

Comment: Can you create a github repo with your code? This way would be easier to run your app and check your code. Another thing I would suggest you is to try to give us more detail about your app. For example, ruby version, rails version, are you using turbolinks? It's happening on development or production?

Comment: By the way I update your the code of your question and I'm seeing that your javascript manifiesto (application.js) calls turbolinks, but if I remember good, you need to add data-turbolinks-track="reload" to your assets helpers. Check https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code in your `application.html.erb`

from:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

to this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```